# SQL commands showing up as string

Tags: sql, string, sqlcommand, quotations

This is my code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['loginemail'])."'AND 
    password='".md5(md5($_POST['loginemail']) .$_POST['loginpassword']). "'LIMIT 1";
```

In my text editor, the AND and LIMIT commands show up as strings.  I cannot figure out why.  Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to add a space before `AND` and `LIMIT`.

Comment: Tried that, still showing up as part of the string.  The code runs, though.  I'm using Sublime if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think its Sublime problem, CMIIW, if it realy matter for you you can change the code like this..

```
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['loginemail']);
  $password = md5(md5($_POST['loginemail']) .$_POST['loginpassword']);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND 
            password='$password' LIMIT 1";
```

Note: I assume it's php code..

Comment: Yes it is PHP code.  I did do that but, apparently I didn't need to because the code runs.  I'm new to programming so I assumed it wouldn't run since the commands looked like they were part of a string.  Thanks!